# Signal emitted from QThread never received

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Here are the code snippets. The thread class that will do some work:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    MyThread(QWidget* parent) : QThread(parent) {}

 signals:
    void results(size_t added);

 private:
    void run() override { emit results(7); }
};
```

The main window class:

```
class MyMain : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    MyMain(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QMainWindow(parent) {}

 private slots:
    void imagesAdded(size_t added) { qDebug() << "images added"; }

 private:
    void test() {
        MyThread* thread = new MyThread(this);
        connect(thread, &MyThread::results, this, &MyMain::imagesAdded);
        connect(thread, &MyThread::finished, thread, &QObject::deleteLater);
        thread->start();
    }
 };
```

In the debugger, I can see the "results" signal connects successfully and that the signal is emitted, however, it is never received.

Comment: QObject destructor docs: "All signals to and from the object are automatically disconnected, and **any pending posted events for the object are removed from the event queue**" - you might have an issue there

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't the signal be emitted in run() before the destructor is called? If that isn't guaranteed to be the case, is there a way to wait until the signal has been processed before exiting?

Comment: You could make the connection type to the `MyThread::results` signal [`Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Comment: That did it, thank you. I'm used to PyQt which handles a lot of that automatically

Comment: This really doesn't make sense though.  As pointed out the docs for [`QObject` dtor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject) state `"...and any pending posted events for the object are removed from the event queue."`.  But the events due to the signal being emitted aren't *for* the `QObject` being destructed -- they are *from* it.  Can't help feeling there's something else going on here.  An emitter shouldn't have to hang around until all emitted signals have been processed.  Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: I agree with you, it didn't make sense to me. Basically what I posted was the minimum working example I extracted from the much larger application. I created a QThread that just emitted a signal so I could test catching it.

Comment: Naive question; if the run() method starts the event loop, does its prompt exit after emitting the signal also stop the event loop?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to write something like `moveToThread` and `exec()` and ...
as I underestand from your question I write this example and run it:

**In mythread.h**

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class MyThread: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyThread();

protected:
    void  run();

signals:
    void  results(int);
};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

**In mythread.cpp**

```
#include "mythread.h"

MyThread::MyThread():
    QThread(nullptr)
{
    moveToThread(this);
}

void  MyThread::run()
{
    emit  results(7);

    exec();
}
```

**In mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void  imagesAdded(int added)
    {
        qDebug() << "images added" << added;
    }

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**In mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mythread.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MyThread *thread = new MyThread();
    connect(thread, &MyThread::results, this, &MainWindow::imagesAdded);
    connect(thread, &MyThread::finished, thread, &QObject::deleteLater);
    thread->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**The output :**

[image]